# Android SearchView - change cursor color

Tags: java, android, search, themes

I am trying to change the cursor color of my SearchView which I instantiate and add in my action bar like this:

```
MenuItem findItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) findItem.getActionView();
```

Xml code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

      <item android:id="@+id/menu_action_search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
          app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

And my activity has a Toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

            style="@style/EActionBar"

            />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Is there a way to override an existing style and change the cursor color of the autocomplete text view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following steps to change cursor color.

**Step 1:** Define your own cursor drawable which placed in `res/drawable` folder.

**my_cursor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#0f0"/>
    <size android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Step 2:** Add this code into `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem findItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) findItem.getActionView();

    // Add this code
    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchTextView = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    try {
        Field field = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.my_cursor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore exception
    }

    // Your logic code here

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: This method works, but like this: final android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)
                searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text); ...             field.set(searchAutoComplete, R.drawable.white_cursor);
 So field is needed from the textbox of searchview, not the searchview itself

Comment: @AndreiF Please take a look my answer carefully, I set on textbox of search view already.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just woke up when I tested the code, didn't even drink my coffee. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Happy coding :)

Comment: searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text) -
for androidx

Answer (score 2):

From Android Q and up you can do this easily in code. First, find your searchView:

```
SearchView search = findViewById(R.id.search);
```

Then find the searchText field using your searchView:

```
EditText searchText = search.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

Then use this to change the color of the cursor:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    searchText.setTextCursorDrawable(R.drawable.cursor_primary);
}
```

You also need to create a drawable for each color you wish to use. In my case above it's cursor_primary.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <size android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

That's all!

**Update 8th of July 2022**

I later discovered that the drawable isn't properly updated until restarting the app. So, instead of using drawables, use this:

```
searchText.getTextCursorDrawable().setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

..and that one works as it should!